# an example for spherical harmonic

Tags: sequences-and-series, functional-analysis, fourier-series, harmonic-analysis

Let $S=\{z\in \mathbb{C}: |z|=1\}$ be the circle of  $\mathbb{C}$. We consider the applications  $h^{p}(z)$ defined on $\Bbb{C}\ni z\to\mathbb{C}$ with $(p\in \mathbb{N}^*)$  such that :

1. $h^{p}(rw)=r^ph^{p}(w),\quad r>0$ and  $\int_{S}h^{p}(w)d\sigma(w)=0$ where  $d\sigma(w)$ is the  Lebesgue measure on  $S$.
2. $\int_{S}|h^{p}(w)|^2d\sigma(w)=1$ and $\int_{S} h^{p}(w)\overline{h^{q}(w)}d\sigma(w)=\delta_{p,q}$.

Put $\Gamma:=\{ g(w)=\sum_{p\geq0} a^ph^p(w) (w\in S):  ||g||^2=\int_{S} |g(w)|^2d\sigma(w)=\sum^{\infty}_{p\geq0}|a^p|^2<\infty \}$ with $a_p\in \mathbb{C}$

By using 1 et 2 on can shows:  $\Gamma:=\{ g(w)=\sum_{p\geq0} a^ph^p(w) (w\in S): \sum^{\infty}_{p\geq0}|a^p|^2<\infty    \}$ with  $a_p\in \mathbb{C}$.

Now, put $\Gamma_r=\{g\in \Gamma:   \int_{S^1}|g(w)|^rd\sigma(w) <\infty\},\quad r>2$ so $\Gamma_r\subset \Gamma$.

My question is.  I m looking for an elemnt $g\in \Gamma$ such that $g\not\in \Gamma_r$.

Thank you a lot of.

Comment: So you are looking for an element of $L^2(S, \Bbb C)$ that is not in $L^r(S, \Bbb C)$ for any $r > 2$.

Comment: Exactly. Can give me such example.